# In fish, what are the pros and cons of a function call versus sourcing a "partial" file?

Tags: function, shell, syntax, fish

Say for example you have a few different fish functions for scaffolding different types of projects, but within each you'd like to have a reusable block for running some git commands.

So you could create a separate function, and call it from the other functions, or you could take the separate function file, remove the `function name -d "description"` and `end` lines out of it, and then from the other functions just invoke it with `source /path/to/partial`.

So I'm wondering when a person should use one method instead of the other.

Comment: I don't use fish but if the question is should you use a function or source a file from disk each time you need to use it then I would imagine the answer is use a function. It should be much quicker and means your function contents can't change on you in the middle of a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using functions gives you a few advantages over sourcing a file:

1. You can tab-complete function names, and add custom completions to tab-complete their arguments
2. They can be modified using `funced` and `funcsave`
3. There's a standard place for them in `~/.config/fish/functions`
4. They can be [autoloaded](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_autoload).

The one advantage of sourcing a file is that it can introduce variables into the caller's scope. For example, `set var value` inside a sourced file will be scoped to the caller's function. (Of course you can make the variable explicitly global from a function or a sourced file: `set -g var value`).